# How to launch docker during jenkins pipeline and remain in same slave slot?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

During my pipeline, I want to execute a Dockerfile, create a docker, launch it and continue execution of the following steps in the created container. I don't want that container to take a new jenkins slave slot as none is available.

I already did something similar with a Jenkins Multibranch project but can't use this approach this time as this is a special job that runs on all branches of a repo at once. The multibranch approach would not make sense.

When that job launches, it is in facts a few hundreads instance of the same job that get launched but each pointing to a different git repo. Those jobs take all the available slots on the slaves. Then, they try to launch the container and there is no available slot. I would like to re-use the same slot and continue, like the Multibranch pipeline job is doing.

Then, I tried running the checkout on Master and then launching the docker on a different node. That might work but it implies a lot of work on the master and a lot of copies of repos from the master to the slave. I don't really like that solution. In facts, I don't even know how to copy the Dockerfile to the new slave before trying to execute it.

```
pipeline {

   agent {label 'docker'}

   stages {

      stage('Base Dockerfile checkout') {
         steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
            branches: [[name: 'master']], 
               doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
               extensions: [[$class: 'RelativeTargetDirectory', 
               relativeTargetDir: 'gipc_synthesis']], 
               submoduleCfg: [], 
               userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@camtl1bitmirror.gad.local:7999/mtlstash/mvt/gipc_synthesis.git']]]
            ) 
         }


      } 

      stage('In Container steps') {

         agent {
            dockerfile {
               dir 'gipc_synthesis/dockerBuild/docker_SRC'
               label "docker"
               args '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd -u 0:0'
            }
         }

         steps {
            // Do something in the container
...
```

Using this just stalls my whole jenkins slaves farm as all slots gets filled with the checkout part and then no slot is available to launch the containers.